# Assigning to namespace typescript

Tags: typescript, namespaces, intellisense

I would like to assign to namespaces with dot notation like this:

```
namespace item {}

item.item1 = {
  name: "Some Item"
}

item.item2 = {
  name: "Some Item"
}
```

This errors with: `Property 'item1' does not exist on type 'typeof item'.`

Now this works:

```
  namespace item {
    export const item3 = {
      name: "Some Item"
    }
  }
  namespace item {
    export const item4 = {
      name: "Some Item"
    }
  }
```

But it's so wordy and ugly that I would prefer not to use it. Is there something I can do in the namespace declaration that would make the first version work? Something like this would make sense to me:

```
namespace item {
  [key: string]: ItemType
}
```

Some of my objectives:

- Want to be able to use intellisense to autocomplete on `item.`,
  should show item1, item2, etc.
- Set items in different files and not all in the same bracket.

Comment: why a namespace for this? shouldn't this just be an object?

Comment: @DanielA.White new to TS so maybe i'm doing it comopletely wrong, like this? `const item = {
  [key: string]: any
}
`

Comment: @DanielA.White very new to TS here. If I do something like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEloFtUG9iqoDaA1lAJ4BcqAzhDOAOYC61CY5wAvsMEgPZg6qENlQBePF1QIaGbL1FQsAOiVYAjBLwFUYBFijUARAGV+h+cuPcZczMsXY12AEzb8hfYZPnLDrBseUGcgA for example it doesn't autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are not made to have variable keys.

If you want to define namespace and assign later, use

```
namespace A {
  export declare let n: number;
}
A.n = 123;
```

If you want to export multiple items, do

```
namespace A {
  export const item1: ItemType = {name: '123'};
  export const item2: ItemType = {name: '123'};
}
```

If you want to have an object with unknown properties, use

```
let A: Record<string, ItemType> = {}
A.whatever = {name: '123'}

// or Partial<Record<'a'|'b', ItemType>>
let B: {[K in 'a'|'b']:?: ItemType} = {}
B.a = {name: '123'}
```

Namespaces themselves are syntactic sugar meaning

```
A = ((A) => {
   A.item1 = {name: 123};
   A.item2 = {name: 123};
   return A;
})(A ?? {})
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to have object with unknown properties so something like option3. The issue is that that intellisense does not autocomplete `A.` and show me `whatever`. The wordy namespace I had above does. Is that the only way to have intellisense work and still have not all the options be in the same bracket?